# How to preserve all Yammer history?

Tags: export, yammer

I need to download, export or somehow save the last few years of our group Yammer account for my company. We are switching to a new domain, and don't want to lose all the discussions and files. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

When you change domains it is possible to merge Yammer networks. This allows the old network to exist as an external network you can access. Merges must be requested through a support ticket to Microsoft.

The alternative is to use the Data Export feature to get a ZIP file of all messages in CSV format and files posted.

Comment: Good answer! Could you perhaps add a screenshot of the "merge Yammer networks" option, so it is clear where to find it?

Comment: This is not exposed to end users or admins, but there is some minimal information at https://success.yammer.com/integrations/network-architecture/. It requires a support ticket to be filed with Microsoft support. Yammer is a Microsoft product.

Comment: Ah, OK. Maybe you could add to your answer that a support ticket is needed to do the merge.